# Spring java config: bean config after component scan

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

I have the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.xyz.svc")
public class SvcConfig { 
    @Autowired private Filter filter1;
    @Autowired private Filter filter2;
    @Autowired private Filter filter3;  

    @Bean
    public List<Filter> filters() {
        // Filters are added in the desired order of execution
        return ImmutableList.of(
                filter1,
                filter2,
                filter3);
    }
}
```

When `leadFilters()` method is run all the components that it depends on (ie `filter1`, `filter2`, `filter3`) are null. Basically, these components are registered through `@ComponentScan`. The problem is `leadFilters()` method is getting executed before `@ComponentScan`.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Spring should calculate correctly the dependency tree. Did you enable annotation driven injection by `@AnnotationDrivenConfig` or `<context:annotation-config/>`?

Comment: There is no such annotation (@AnnotationDrivenConfig)

Comment: @Sotirios' answer is helpful (and highlights the autowiring problem you will have even if you can get the three dependencies injected). But you have to ask yourself why the `@Bean` is needed so early in the context life cycle. It shouldn't be. Maybe if you post a stack trace from the exception that would be a clue?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't, reliably. A `@Configuration` class is a `@Component` that is meant to register bean definitions through `@Bean` annotated methods. If a request for a bean (handled through a `@Bean` method) comes in before the `BeanPostProcessor` that handles `@Autowired`, then you will see the behavior you are describing.

Note that the following will cause you problems as Spring won't know which to inject.

```
@Autowired
private Filter filter1;
@Autowired
private Filter filter2;
@Autowired
private Filter filter3;
```

Assuming this was just an example, you could refactor so that instead of having `@Component` classes for these filters, you instead declare `@Bean` methods for them.

```
@Bean
public Filter filter1() {
    return new FilterImpl1();
}
@Bean
public Filter filter2() {
    return new FilterImpl2();
}
@Bean
public Filter filter3() {
    return new FilterImpl3();
}
```

You can then use these beans in your other `@Bean` method

```
@Bean
public List<Filter> filters() {
    // Filters are added in the desired order of execution
    return ImmutableList.of(
            filter1(),
            filter2(),
            filter3());
}
```